# cannot run aidegen, missing the dataclasses module

Tags: python, android-source

I have been using aidegen to develop on AOSP.

For some reason, I cannot get it to work on one of the build tree I am working on. I get this error despite trying to use it in a venv, without venv, each time while having installed the dataclasses module :

```
$: aidegen 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/Soong.python_4y5nr8sq/__soong_entrypoint_redirector__.py", line 6, in <module>
    runpy._run_module_as_main("aidegen.aidegen_main", alter_argv=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/Soong.python_4y5nr8sq/aidegen/aidegen_main.py", line 50, in <module>
    from aidegen.lib import aidegen_metrics
  File "/tmp/Soong.python_4y5nr8sq/aidegen/lib/aidegen_metrics.py", line 24, in <module>
    from aidegen.lib import common_util
  File "/tmp/Soong.python_4y5nr8sq/aidegen/lib/common_util.py", line 40, in <module>
    from atest import atest_utils
  File "/tmp/Soong.python_4y5nr8sq/atest/atest_utils.py", line 45, in <module>
    from dataclasses import dataclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
```

```
$: pip install dataclasses
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in <path_to_venv>/venv_3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: Are you using the same python that's associated with venv_3?

Comment: I do not really know. I am not sure what is actually executed by aidegen. It seems to use runpy I am not sure if this is a useful information